# Multiple calls to "datatable" within R function

Tags: r

I'd like to be able to display different kinds of outputs within an R function, like so:

```
vis_data <- function(data) {
    #print(datatable(data))
    datatable(data)
    print("Some output")
    #a <- 2 + 2
}
```

I understand that R only displays the last output within if statements and functions, unless you enclose it in a print statement.

Unfortunately, even if I enclose the datatable function in a print statement, as in the commented-out line, the above function still does not show the datatable.

If I comment out the `print("Some output")` line and uncomment the `"a <- 2 + 2"` line so that this is the final statement of the function, the datatable doesn't display, even though `"a <- 2 + 2"` doesn't display anything either.

My goal with this function is to take in a dataset and display multiple aspects of a single case, so I need to figure out a flexible way to display data tables, graphs, and text. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Which `datatable` function is this? Which package are you using? This must not be the normal "data.table" package.

Comment: I'm guessing the `DT` package. It's such an inconvenient lexicographic difference ... similar to why I dislike `dplyr`'s choice of the name `filter`.

Comment: Yes, it's datatable from the DT package.